# How do I get my CUDA specs on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, cuda

I'm accessing a remote machine that has a good nVidia card for CUDA computing, but I can't find a way to know which card it uses and what are the CUDA specs (version, etc.). I used the "lspci" command on the terminal, but there is no sign of a nvidia card. I'm pretty sure it has a nVidia card, and nvcc seems to be installed.

But I really want to figure out the card and CUDA specs. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can find where the CUDA SDK directory has been installed then you can just run the `deviceQuery` example which will tell you all you need to know and more. The executable should be at `$(SDK)/C/bin/linux/release/deviceQuery` - if it's not there then you may need to build the samples first:

```
$ cd $(SDK)
$ make
$ ./C/bin/linux/release/deviceQuery
```

The CUDA SDK directory is typically named `NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK` (more recent CUDA versions) or just `NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK` (older CUDA versions).

Comment: Isn't there any other way? It seems the admin hasn't installed the sdk...or has deleted it. Maybe I'll just download and build it myself. Thanks.

Comment: You can make your custom deviceQuery in your home directory :)

Comment: @mieli: if you have nvcc installed then it would be unusual for there to be no SDK, but as you say it may have been deleted

Comment: @PaulR nvcc comes with the CUDA toolkit. The CUDA toolkit and the CUDA SDK are two different things. There are many instances people (mostly those that have been using CUDA for a while), install the toolkit but not the SDK.

Answer (score 11):

If you have all of Cuda installed, then just run:

`nvidia-smi`

Comment: This doesn't tell you stuff like maximum CUDA grid sizes, cpabilities etc.

Comment: Running `nvidia-smi -L` will just list the GPUs. If you don't have the dev kit installed, you can use this information to look up additional specs online.